# Negative Number to Non-Integer Power in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, nan, exponent

I'm writing a script that has to do something like this at one point: `Math.pow(-2,1.5)`. The result should be approximately -2.82843, but instead, Javascript returns `NaN`. (I tried this in both Google Chrome 17 and Mozilla Firefox 11.) If the exponent is an integer, such as in `Math.pow(-2,3)`, then Javascript will return the right answer, which, in this case, is -8. Positive numbers also correctly raise to non-integer powers; `Math.pow(2,1.5)` evaluates to approximately 2.8284271247461903. Is there any way that I can get Javascript to calculate the value of a negative number to a non-integer power?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Math.pow(-2, 1.5)` returns NaN because there is no real number which equals -2 taken to the power 1.5. There is a complex number with this property, but `Math.pow()` doesn't do calculations using complex numbers.

This simple transformation demonstrates that this is the case:

(-2)<sup>1.5</sup> = (-2)<sup>1</sup> * (-2)<sup>0.5</sup> = (-2) * sqrt(-2) = (-2) * i * sqrt(2) = -2i * sqrt(2)

Comment: Is there a library that I can use to compute complex numbers in Javascript?

Comment: Also, why is it that if I type -2^1.5 into a calculator, it gives me a real number?

Comment: Well, it's easy to implement with one prototype and a few functions (formulae needed are in all introductory books to complex analysis). [Google search](http://google.com/#q=complex%20numbers%20javascript%20library) turns up [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Language-Basics/Complexclasstorepresentcomplexnumbers.htm) and a few others. They seem to lack operations like pow() or sqrt(), but again these are relatively easy to express in terms of real functions (one caveat being multivaluedness of some complex functions, but you can often just pick the most convenient value).

Comment: -2^1.5 is not the same as Math.pow(-2, 1.5). The latter is (-2)^1.5. JavaScript expression for -2^1.5 is -Math.pow(2, 1.5) which will not return NaN.

Comment: Oh, whoops. I should have known that. I never made that mistake in math class, but I just made it outside of math class.